# Click button on html page fetched using HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, html, httpwebresponse

I have an html page in a whole HttpWebResponse this way:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sslServerHost);
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

When I go to the same URL in a browser, I get a page with two buttons. I need to click one of them:

```
<form id="confirmationForm" name="confirmationForm" action="/oauth/oauth/authorize"
                  method="post">
     <input name="user_oauth_approval" value="true" type="hidden"/>
     <button name="authorize" type="submit" class="allow-button">
          Allow access
     </button>
</form>
```

How can I click the button with name "authorize" programmatically using the HttpWebResponse that I got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to load up the page in a web browser with an HTTP proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) running then click the button and see the response. Copy that out then use that for the request to click the button.